# How to add 'postcss config' to laravel mix?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

No matter how hard I try, but the plugins never seem to catch on.

I tried to add the method .postCss - nothing

I tried to give the path to the config also did not help

```
mix.sourceMaps('source-map').react('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .webpackConfig({
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          loaders: [
              { loader: 'style-loader' },
              { loader: 'css-loader', options: { modules: true, importLoaders: 1, localIdentName: '[folder]_[name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]' } },
              { loader: 'postcss-loader', 
                options: {  plugins: () => {
                postcssPresetEnv({
                  stage: 3,
                  features: {
                      'browsers': browsers,
                      'nesting-rules': true,
                  }
                })
            }
          }
        }
      ]}
     ],
  }
})
```

Comment: Here is an example I used: https://github.com/adamwathan/laravel-preset/blob/master/src/stubs/webpack.mix.js (though I see you have a more elaborate setup)

Comment: Thanks man .options({
    postCss: [
      require('postcss-import')(),
      require('tailwindcss')(/* './path/to/tailwind.js' */),
      require('postcss-nesting')(),
    ]
  })